How do i remove viewport error for Progressive web app when doing audit
I have my web app optimized for PWA it passed the check when i used lighthouse chrome tools but when i deploy the site and check again i get this error.
The viewport size of 412px does not match the window size of 420px.
So PWA only passes on localhost
I have already kept the viewport meta tag
Also tried adding media queries for exactly 420 and 425
cleared history and cache on browser
but still getting the error
